# Creating Python button saves edited file

Tags: python, function, tkinter, save

I'm new with tkinter and was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction. I'm wondering on how to over write a previously saved file without the saveasdialog, like how an actual save function would be implemented. I'm currently using it to save a .txt file with different points for my project.
The save as function works. Would I have to find the directory and change it somehow? Is there any easier way to do this?
Heres what I have so far for both save and saveas:

```
def saveFile(self):
    method = self.method.current()
    try:
        with open(self.f,'w') as outputFile:
            if(method==0):
                method.write()
    except AttributeError:
        self.save_as

def saveFileAs(self):

    f = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt")
    method = self.method.current()
    #used to write to .txt file and does save
    if(method == 0):
    # f.write() to save to .txtfile
```

Comment: What do you mean, "an actual save function"? If it correctly saves your file to disk, it's an actual save function. If you didn't have a call to `asksaveasfile()` or `asksaveasfilename()`, you'd have to implement it in some other way. Are you wondering how to create a "save as" function from scratch?

Comment: What I mean by save function as in the asksaveasfile() does save it onto the disk, but would there be some way for me to edit the same file and then replace it onto the same file/path without having a dialog box appear? Maybe a check whether or not the file exist then replace the text. Thanks

Comment: What dialog box? The dialog box asking where you want to save the file? Or the dialog box asking if you're sure you want to overwrite a file that exists? Or you mean something like a "Save," as opposed to "Save As...", that silently overwrites the current working file?

Comment: Yes I mean save that silently overwrites the current working file, just wondering if there's a different method I don't know about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a save function that silently overwrites the current file, the basic thing to do is save a reference to the file name/location that the user chose, and then the next time you save you can reuse it instead of asking for a new one. The following (taken from a program of mine) has a "plain" save function that checks if there's a save file name on record, and either uses it (if it exists) or goes to the "save as" function. The plain version happens to have a `return` value so that it can interact with a load (open) function elsewhere in the program (asks the user whether to save unsaved work before loading a new file).

```
def save_plain(self, *args):
    """
    A plain save function. If there's no preexisting file name,
    uses save_as() instead.
    Parameter:
        *args: may include an event
    """
    if self.savename: # if there's a name
        self.save(self.savename) # then use it
    elif self.save_as(): # else, use save_as instead
        return True # successful save returns True
    return False # else, return False

def save_as(self, *args):
    """
    A save as function, which asks for a name and only retains it if it was given
    (canceling makes empty string, which isn't saved).
    Parameter:
        *args: may include an event
    """
    temp = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".txt", \
    filetypes=(('Text files', '.txt'),('All files', '.*'))) # ask for a name
    if temp: # if we got one,
        self.savename = temp # retain it
        self.save(temp) # and pass it to save()
        return True
    return False

def save(self, filename):
    """
    Does the actual saving business of writing a file with the given name.
    Parameter:
        filename (string): the name of the file to write
    """
    try: # write the movelist to a file with the specified name
        with open(filename, 'w', encoding = 'utf-8-sig') as output:
            for item in self.movelist:
                output.write(item + "\n")
        self.unsaved_changes = False # they just saved, so there are no unsaved changes
    except: # if that doesn't work for some reason, say so
        messagebox.showerror(title="Error", \
        message="Error saving file. Ensure that there is room and you have write permission.")
```